# Overcoming Type Erasure in Scala with TypeTag

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I have the following case class:

```
trait Event
object Event {
  case class ProducerStreamActivated[T <: KafkaMessage](kafkaTopic: String, stream: SourceQueueWithComplete[T]) extends Event
}

trait KafkaMessage
object KafkaMessage {

  case class DefaultMessage(message: String, timestamp: DateTime) extends KafkaMessage {
    def this() = this("DEFAULT-EMPTY-MESSAGE", DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
  }

  case class DefaultMessageBundle(messages: Seq[DefaultMessage], timeStamp: DateTime) extends KafkaMessage {
    def this() = this(Seq.empty, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
  }
}
```

In one of my Actor, I have the following method that identifies the actual Type:

```
class KafkaPublisher[T <: KafkaMessage: TypeTag] extends Actor {

  def paramInfo[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
    val targs = typeOf[T] match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
    println(s"type of $x has type arguments $targs")
  }

  implicit val system = context.system
  val log = Logging(system, this.getClass.getName)

  override final def receive = {
    case ProducerStreamActivated(_, stream) =>
      paramInfo(stream)
      log.info(s"Activated stream for Kafka Producer with ActorName >> ${self.path.name} << ActorPath >> ${self.path} <<")
      context.become(active(stream))

    case other =>
      log.warning("KafkaPublisher got some unknown message while producing: " + other)
  }

  def active(stream: SourceQueueWithComplete[KafkaMessage]): Receive = {
    case msg: T =>
      stream.offer(msg)

    case other =>
      log.warning("KafkaPublisher got the unknown message while producing: " + other)
  }
}
object KafkaPublisher {

  def props[T <: KafkaMessage: TypeTag] =
    Props(new KafkaPublisher[T])
}
```

I create an instance of the ProducerStreamActivated(...) in a parent Actor like this:

```
val stream = producerStream[DefaultMessage](producerProperties)
  def producerStream[T: Converter](producerProperties: Map[String, String]): SourceQueueWithComplete[T] = {
    if (Try(producerProperties("isEnabled").toBoolean).getOrElse(false)) {
      log.info(s"Kafka is enabled for topic ${producerProperties("publish-topic")}")
      val streamFlow = flowToKafka[T](producerProperties)
      val streamSink = sink(producerProperties)
      source[T].via(streamFlow).to(streamSink).run()
    } else {
      // We just Log to the Console and by pass all Kafka communication
      log.info(s"Kafka is disabled for topic ${producerProperties("publish-topic")}")
      source[T].via(flowToLog[T](log)).to(Sink.ignore).run()
    }
  }
```

When I now print the Type that is contained in the stream SourceQueueWithComplete[T] in my child actor, I get to see the base class KafkaMessage contained instead of the expected DefaultMessage. Any ideas how to mitigate this?

Comment: Just a wild guess... but isn't your problem one where you lost information not because of JVM (type erasure), but because you serialized it when publishing on Kafka, and then trying to match on message before decoding it back into your original type?

Comment: I'm not publishing it yet to Kafka, as you can see in my producerStream method, the producerProperties("isEnabled").toBoolean is set to false. It is therefore disabled and I have a flow that writes to a Log file! It can be seen in the flowToLog function which is then supposed to write to a Log file!

Comment: Try ClassTag instead of TypeTag?

Comment: ClassTag did not work either! I originally had the ClassTag and then switched to the TypeTag given its advance features than the ClassTag

Comment: @sparkr Did you try to generalize your problem, make it simpler and more concise? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should help you. I know a bit about this topic (I even wrote a beginner-friendly [blogpost](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20) about it) but there's just too much going on here. At first I just hit 'back' in my browser, but then I figured I'd give you some feedback. If it's really a typetag problem, it should be reproducible without all the kafka / actors / queues / streams / publishers / messages / producers infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `KafkaPublisher`'s `receive` method, you pattern match on a `ProducerStreamActivated` without any type parameters (you can't match on one with parameters because of type erasure), and in that method, the implicit `TypeTag` passed to `paramInfo` is decided at compile-time, at which point it is just a `TypeTag[KafkaMessage]`.

One way you should be able to work around this is to just have the `ProducerStreamActivated` class carry its own type tag with it, i.e.:

```
case class ProducerStreamActivated[T <: KafkaMessage](kafkaTopic: String, stream: SourceQueueWithComplete[T])(implicit val tag: TypeTag[T]) extends Event
```

Then rather than summoning one implicitly in the `receive` method, just do `msg.tag`.

This should work because at the point you actually create the `ProducerStreamActivated`, you do have the compile-time type parameter info (it's `DefaultMessage`) and so that will be the type tag the compiler fills in, and you can then just keep a reference to that.

Comment: If you look at my comments to the post above, I just mentioned that even with the TypeTag implicit, it still could not resolve!